# Записать (добавить) строку в уже скомпилированный exe файл Go

Tags: windows, golang, exe

Как в golang изменить строку в уже скомпилированном exe файле?
Действия будут происходить на стороне клиента, программа будет уже установлена и работать, необходимо изменить определённую строку в этой программе.

Вот код на purebasic, как реализовать тоже самое на golang и желательно без winApi.

```
    Procedure.s MainPart(Text.s) 
  ;Simple text-Box 
  OpenWindow(0,0,0,240,160,"Notes",#PB_Window_SystemMenu|#PB_Window_ScreenCentered) 
  ;CreateGadgetList(WindowID(0)) 
  StringGadget(0,5,5,230,150,Text,#ES_MULTILINE|#WS_VSCROLL|#WS_HSCROLL|#ES_AUTOHSCROLL|#ES_AUTOVSCROLL) 
  Repeat:Until WaitWindowEvent() = #PB_Event_CloseWindow;EventCloseWindow 
  ProcedureReturn GetGadgetText(0) 
EndProcedure 


;Get program and temp-folder name 
program.s= Space(1000):GetModuleFileName_(0,program,1000) 
temp.s=    Space(1000):GetTempPath_(1000,temp) 

;Construct Clone-Name 
clone.s=   temp+"_"+GetFilePart(program) 


;Check mode by parameter 
mode.s=ProgramParameter() 
If mode="clone" ;I am the clone 
  ;Check if another instance is running (cause makes no sense here) 
  Mutex=CreateMutex_(0,1,"Mischas Notes") 
  Error=GetLastError_() 
  If Mutex<>0 And Error=0 
    program=ProgramParameter() 
    Size=FileSize(program) 

    ReadFile(0,program) 
      FileSeek(0,Size-12) 
      If ReadLong(0) = 1234321 ;this is a sign for us that there are resources inside 
        Size=ReadLong(0) 
        resourcesize=ReadLong(0) 
        FileSeek(0,Size) 
        *res=AllocateMemory(resourcesize) 
        ReadData(0,*res,resourcesize) 
        resource.s=PeekS(*res) 
      EndIf 
      FileSeek(0,0) 
      *header=AllocateMemory(Size) 
      ReadData(0,*header,Size) ;Put the small main-program in the pocket (alternate do this in the end) 
    CloseFile(0) 

    newtext.s=MainPart(resource) ;The main-program 

    If newtext <> resource ;Ok, now we construct new program with new resources 
      resourcesize=Len(newtext) + 1 
      *res=AllocateMemory(resourcesize) 
      PokeS(*res,newtext) 
      SetFileAttributes_(program,#FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL) ;maybe its write-protected 

      CreateFile(1,program) 
        WriteData(1,*header,Size)         ;program-part 
        WriteData(1,*res,resourcesize)    ;resource-part 
        WriteLong(1,1234321)              ;Our sign 
        WriteLong(1,Size)                 ;Adress of resources 
        WriteLong(1,resourcesize)         ;Size of resources 
      CloseFile(1) 
    EndIf 
    RunProgram(program,"killclone","",0)  
  EndIf 
  CloseHandle_(Mutex) 
ElseIf mode="killclone" ;Delete clone of program 
  Sleep_(500) 
  DeleteFile(clone) 
Else ;normal mode  
  ;Create and start clone 
  If FileSize(clone) = -1 
    CopyFile(program,clone) 
  EndIf 
  RunProgram(clone,"clone "+Chr(34)+program+Chr(34),"",0)  
EndIf 
End
```

https://dropmefiles.com/kUUVj - скомпилированный вариант.

Comment: Если уже скомпилированая то там уже нет строки, там бинарной файл

Comment: Но изменить бинарные данные тоже можно...
В purebasic можно было выделить специальную область в exe файле, а после компиляции изменять.

Comment: Так делать нельзя, точнее можно извратиться и сделать так, но проще хранить данные отдельно в gob файле

Comment: Если только этот файл включить в исполняемый exe.

Comment: Если только этот файл включить в исполняемый exe.
Может есть возможность сделать что то вроде sfx архива?
Первый запуск программа создаёт архив в который будет добавлен генерированный файл и сама программа, после создания программа замещается на созданный архив (разумеется запускает созданный файл и оригинал уничтожается).

Comment: Весь вопрос, зачем весь этот гиморой? проще хранить данные лицезнии (как я понимаю тут задача стоит именно такая) в отдельном файле рядом с *.exe , потому что вы сами подумайте, вот настал тот момент когда вам надо что-то подправить или просто обносить версию вашего *.exe и лицензия слетит.

Comment: Программа содержит множество модулей, все модули обновляются не зависимо от ключевого звена, ключевое звено всего лишь оболочка которая общается с другими модулями, это звено не будет изменятся и обновляться.

Comment: Для Windows есть WinApi UpdateResource https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-updateresourcea 
Есть ли что нибудь подобное для Golang?

Comment: Как дописать в конец файла примерно понимаю, но вот как прочесть и обработать дописанный фрагмент просто не понимаю.